# A normal extension of a number field of given degree that does not split over a given set of finite places

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $S$ be a finite set of non-archimedean places of $K$. Let $n>1$ be a natural number.

> **Question.** Does there exist a *normal* extension $L/K$ of degree $n$ such that $L\otimes_K K_v$ is a field for each $v\in S$ ?

Here $K_v$ denotes the completion of $K$ at $v$.

I know how to construct a not necessarily normal extension. I construct an extension $K'_v/K_v$ of degree $n$ for each $v\in S$, choose a primitive element $\alpha_v\in K_v'$, and write the irreducible polynomial
$P_v(X)={\rm Irr}(\alpha_v, K_v', X)$.
Then I approximate the constructed polynomials
$P_v(X)\in K_v[X]$ by a polynomial $P(X)\in K[X]$ and define $L=K[X]/(P)$. Can this construction be modified so that it would give a *normal* extension $L/K$?

Alternatively, can one use class field theory to construct an *abelian* (hence, normal) extension $L/K$ with required properties?

Comment: Unless $8|n$ and $S$ contains a prime extending $2$, it works with cyclic extensions by Grunwald-Wang.

Comment: *"How can one construct"*: are you asking whether the statement is true, or are you asking about an explicit construction of a fact you know to hold true? in the first case, I would rephrase.

Comment: Thank you, @JoachimKönig, but I need the general case.

Comment: Yes (with $L/K$ cyclic) by Artin-Tate Ch X, Thm 6.

Comment: Thank you, @user491858. This is exactly what I need!

Comment: @user491858: Please have a look at  [my new question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/466255/4149).