# Constructing a cyclic extension $L$ with given local behavior of a global field $K$ such that $L$ is normal over a subfield $F$ of $K$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory, global-fields

Let $F$ be a global field without real places
(that is, a function field or a totally imaginary number field).
Let $K/F$ be a cyclic extension of degree $n$.
Let $S$ be a ${\rm Gal}(K/F)$-invariant finite set of non-archimedean places of $K$.

Let $r\ge 1$ be an integer. By Theorem X.6 in the book "Class field theory" by Artin and Tate,
there exists a cyclic extension $L/K$ of degree $n^r$ such that all local extensions
$L_w/K_v$  for $v\in S$ are of degree $n^r$.

> **Question.** Can one construct such an extension $L/K$ with the additional property  that $L$ is normal over $F$?

Note that $L$ is normal over $F$ if and only if the norm subgroup $N_{L/K}(C_L)\subset C_K$ is
${\rm Gal}(K/F)$-invariant, where $C_L$ and $C_K$ are the corresponding idèle class groups.

Comment: Dear Mikhail, I don't think so, for local reasons. Consider the case when $n=n'=p$ prime. Then if $L/F$ is Galois, it is abelian, so one can try to set things up where local conditions force $L/F$ to be both cyclic and non-cyclic. For example, if the local conditions imply that a prime $\mathfrak{q}$ in $F$ is inert in $L$, then $L/F$ (if Galois) has to be cyclic, since all unramified extensions are cyclic.

Comment: Take $n=n'=3$ for convenience. Let $P$ in $F$ be a prime of norm $p \not\equiv 1\bmod 3^2$ which is tamely ramified in $K/F$. This gives a local obstruction to $L/F$ being cyclic. Now suppose $Q$ in $F$ has norm $q\equiv 2\bmod 3$ and is inert in $K$, and take $S=\{Q\}$. The norm of $Q \mathcal{O}_K$ is $q^3\not\equiv 1\bmod 3$, so there is no degree $3$ ramified (at $Q$) extension $L/K$. Your conditions force $L/F$ to be cyclic, a contradiction. An example: $F=\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$, $K=\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_7)$, $P$ the (unique) prime in $F$ of norm $7$, and $Q$ any prime of norm $2$ in $F$.

Comment: Many thanks indeed!